# For loop on multiple lists in object

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have 10 lists stored in the object `squared.res$squared` that can be called using `squared.res$squared[1]` (list1) `squared.res$squared[2]` list2 etc. I would like to get the number of rows for each list in the object. 
I tried to convert to data frame and do a loop, but the output is empty. I did not manage to produce a data example.
EDIT: squared.res is a list

```
for (i in  1:10) {
dim(do.call(rbind.data.frame, squared.res$squared[i]))[1]
}
```

Comment: its a list as well

Comment: `sapply(squared.res$squared, FUN=dim)` or `sapply(squared.res$squared, FUN=nrow)`

Comment: Lists don't have rows ... (unless they have an additional class like "data.frame"). Please add the output of `str(squared.res$squared[1:2])` to your question.

Comment: sapply(squared.res$squared, FUN=dim) did it.

Comment: Eventually also `lengths(squared.res$squared)` works.

Answer (score 0):

If `squared.res$squared` is a list, it seems that

```
lapply(squared.res$squared, length)
```

should work. Or with `sapply` instead of `lapply`, or `dim` instead of `length` as @jogo proposes.